# How call remote wcf from pcl project

Tags: c#, forms, wcf, xamarin

I need to call a remote wcf from pcl project.

I created xamarin forms solution in Visual Studio 2017

I don't find link to reference service in this project.

Someone can me bring me some help ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem is? What have you tried, what is not working?

Comment: Please read this site https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your Question. So we can help you.

Comment: So, I don't know the best way...